# Sharepoint Table Autopopulates to NO

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I've run into a problem with Sharepoint - I've created a Infopath form, and connected it to a list in Sharepoint. Some of fields in the form are YES/NO questions, with the default set to YES.

I have an excel file with similar fields that I am trying to copy and paste into the table that Infopath has created in Sharepoint. However, when I try to copy and paste a row, all the YES/NO fields autopopulate to NO, even when the field in the excel file is blank.

Notes:
1. If you fill out the Infopath form to submit the data, you can have a YES/NO field be blank.
2. If you try to manually enter in a row through the table view, if you leave a YES/NO field blank, it will automatically change it to NO.

Any help would be very useful.